# How access to the JHipster API when authentication is managed by Keycloak

Tags: postman, jhipster, keycloak

I've built a JHipster application with oauth2 authentication. The latter is implemented by Keycloak through the generated docker-compose file.

Everything works fine in the browser for "human" users. But I need to make some external programs use the API while beng authenticated.

So I started to simulate direct access to API with Postman. I read about XSRF-TOKEN cookie. But to be frank, I don't understand the process of authentication.

Can anyone explain how to perform authenticated requests to the JHipster API regarding keycloak ?

Maybe it isn't the appropriate approach : I also read about implementing a Configuration based on another authentication mecanism, that should be used for controllers exposed on a different endpoint.

Any help figuring out all of that would be really appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

You need machine to machine authentication. Generally Open ID Connect (OIDC) offers `client credentials flow` for this case. So in theory you just enable it in the Keycloak client configuration and you may use it. But it depends on your API auth implementation. Your API very likely uses different OIDC flow for humans and it may not be ready for client credentials flow.

Comment: Ok so I need to add a client allowing the `client credentials flow` in keycloak and ensure APIs are using the token appropriatly. I'm gonna try that. Thk for the tip !

Answer (score 1):

I got it working: Jan's tip show me the way.

Mainly I followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@bcarunmail/securing-rest-api-using-keycloak-and-spring-oauth2-6ddf3a1efcc2).

The solution would be to add a client configured with `Standard flow`, `Service account` and `Authorization` enabled. Then I added the JHipster client scope provided by the generated docker-compose setup.

Once that was configured, I configured the request to use the  Oauth2 authentication. I filled the configuration form for token request according to the tutorial. And I was good to go !

Many thx !